# What's "undefined" in the output of following code ?

Tags: actionscript-3

Am experimenting with an anonymous function :

```
var a:Object = new Object() ;
a.b = new Function()

a.b =function()
{
    trace("hello");
}

trace(a.b())
```

Output : 
hello
undefined

What's undefined ??

Comment: "What's undefined?". A bit like trying to identify a UFO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two trace statements running:

```
trace("hello");

trace(a.b());
```

When you call `trace(a.b())` first `a.b()` is called. `a.b` is simply this function:

```
function()
{
    trace("hello");
}
```

So that runs and outputs "hello".

Now the second trace (`trace(a.b()`) tries to output the result of `a.b()`. The problem is that you do not return anything in `a.b()`, so the result is undefined.

Edit: As JonatanHedborg points out in his comment, the line `a.b = new Function()` is really not needed as you overwrite it on the next line.

If you change this to:

```
var a:Object = new Object() ;

a.b = function()
{
    return "Hello";
}

trace(a.b())
```

You should now see "hello" as the output.

Alternatively, if you change it to this:

```
var a:Object = new Object() ;

a.b = function()
{
    trace("hello");
}

trace(a.b)
```

so that you are tracing the value of a.b instead of the value of the result of a.b() then you should see "hello" and "Function function" (or something similar) as the result.

Comment: the `a.b = new Function()` should not be needed, since it's being overwritten by another definition of a function anyway.

Comment: @JonatanHedborg Agreed. I simply copied his code and changed the part he was having trouble with, but that's a good thing to point out - I'll edit it into the answer.

Comment: Btw, any idea why.. a.b = function():void,  doesnot work then? The void return type specification should ideally remove the undefined problem.

Comment: @VishwasGagrani Since the function returns nothing (void), tracing the return value yields undefined. If you want to trace the return value of your function, it needs to return a proper value :)

Answer (score 1):

It is the return value of the function "b".